# Is there a way to simplify code like this in AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Right now throughout my code I have a lot of duplicates of the following block of code:

```
NSString *imageID = [postURL.path substringFromIndex:1];
NSString *APILink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/%@", imageID];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Client-ID --myID--" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[operationManager GET:APILink
           parameters:nil
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { 
                         ....
```

Is there a way to simplify this into a more reusable code block? I remember subclassing `AFHTTPClient` in AFNetworking 1.0 to accomplish something similar, but I'm confused as to how to do it in AFNetworking 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code into a method that is in a category of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`:

If I analyzed your code correct:

MyServicesAPIAddition.h

```
@interface AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(MyServicesAPIAddition)
+ (void)resourceWithURL:(NSURL*)URL clientID:(NSString *)clientID completionHandler:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))handler;
@end
```

MyServicesAPIAddition.m

```
@implementation AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(MyServicesAPIAddition)
+ (void)resourceWithURL:(NSURL*)URL clientID:(NSString *)clientID completionHandler:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))handler
{
    NSString *imageID = [URL.path substringFromIndex:1];
    NSString *APILink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/%@", imageID];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Client-ID %@", clientID] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[operationManager GET:APILink
           parameters:nil
              success:handler];
}
@end
```

And then:

```
[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager resourceWithURL:postURL clientID:… completionHandler:
^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
{
…
}
```

One wants to add a suffix to the method's name to prevent selector clashes. Me not.